# Android Exception raised during rendering

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, exception

I'm trying to preview my xml layout, but when I open it it gives me the following message:
java.util.Locale.toLanguageTag()Ljava/lang/String;

My java version: javac 1.8.0_25

And I'm using android Studio, below is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:id="@+id/linhaPedidos"
    android:clickable="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"

            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout9">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/numeroPedido"
                        android:text="123456 "
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:duplicateParentState="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout11">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="19/10/2014 às 14:30"
                            android:id="@+id/data_criado"
                            android:duplicateParentState="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:drawableRight="@drawable/seta_hover"

                            android:gravity="center_vertical|right" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/pedidoID"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout10">


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/ViewEndereco"
            android:layout_height="8dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/dot"
            android:layerType="software"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/statusPedido"
            android:text="Status"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I removed some line and it worked just right, past your selector code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say for sure, but double check the `TextView` with the id `data_criado`. You have a fixed text string of "19/10/2014 às 14:30" but for the preview the tools are most likely assuming English/US for the locale.  Convert your strings to resources and put English as well as other translations in place appropriately and this will go away.